# Tables Div grows beyond parent Div, but should adapt to size

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I would like to create a table-component in which the index at the side as well as at the head of the table only moves in the respective direction when scrolling, that worked well so far.

But if I now add data to the data table, the table grows beyond the parent Div. I don't want that. The data table should only be as big as the space in the parent div and the rest should be scrollable.

Information I have received about it suggest to set the parent div to `display: table` or height to 100% but unfortunately it doesn't work as desired.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gssmwf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

**table component template**

```
<div class="table-head">
   <h4>{{tablehead}}</h4>
</div>
<app-index-header [numbers]="generateIndexHeadNumbers 
                  [leftMargin]="getHeaderMargin()"
                  [cellWidths]="headerCellWidth">
</app-index-header>
<div class="table-body">
   <app-index-side [numbers]="generateIndexSideNumbers()"   
                   [cellHeight]="sideCellHeight">
   </app-index-side>
   <div #scroll class="scroll" (scroll)="onScroll()">
       <div class="table-rows" *ngIf="rows.length !== 0">
           <div *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index;" class="table-row">
               <div *ngFor="let cell of row" class="table-cell">{{cell}</div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div *ngIf="rows.length === 0">
           No Data
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**styles**

```
:host{
   display: block;
   background-color: #F2F2F2;
   height: inherit;
 }
 .table-head h4{
     display: block;
     margin-top: 0;
 }
 app-index-header{
     display: flex;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin-right: 17px;
     text-align: center;
 }

 app-index-side{
     margin-bottom: 17px;
     overflow: hidden;
 }


 .table-body{
     display: flex;
 }

 .table-rows{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 .table-row{
     display: table-row;
     border-bottom: 1px solid;
 } 
 .table-row:last-child{
     border-bottom: 0;
 }
 .table-cell{
     min-width: 80px;
     max-width: 120px;
     display: table-cell;
     overflow-wrap: break-word;
     padding: 2px;
     border-right: 1px solid; 
  }
 .table-cell:last-child{
     border-right: 0;
  }
  .scroll{
     overflow: scroll;
  }
```

**Table-Component**

```
import {
    AfterContentChecked,
    Component, ElementRef,
    HostListener,
    Input,
    OnInit, ViewChild,
 } from '@angular/core';
 import {IndexSideComponent} from './index-side/index-side.component';
 import {IndexHeaderComponent} from './index-header/index-header.component';

 @Component({
     selector: 'app-data-table',
     templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
 })
 export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked{

    @Input()
    selectAble: boolean; 

    @Input()
    tablehead  = 'Head';

    @Input()
    rows: string[][];

    @ViewChild(IndexSideComponent, {read: ElementRef})
    indexSide;

    @ViewChild(IndexHeaderComponent, {read: ElementRef})
    indexHeader;

    @ViewChild('scroll')
    scroll;

    headerCellWidth = [];
    sideCellHeight = [];

    @HostListener('window:resize') onWindowResize() {
       // TODO calculate new index-size
    }


    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    ngAfterContentChecked() {
        this.headerCellWidth = this.generateHeaderCellWidth();
        this.sideCellHeight = this.generateSideCellHeight();
        this.cellPadding();
    }

    onScroll(event) {
        this.indexHeader.nativeElement.scrollLeft =   this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollLeft;
        this.indexSide.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop;
    }

    generateHeaderCellWidth() {
        const ret = [];
        const rows = this.elRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('table-row');

        if (rows.length === 0) {
            return [];
        }
        for (const cell of rows[0].children) {
            ret.push(cell.getBoundingClientRect().width);
        }
        return ret;
  }

  generateSideCellHeight() {
     const ret = [];
     const rows = this.elRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('table-row');
     if (rows.length === 0) {
         return ret;
     }
     for (const row of rows) {
         ret.push(row.getBoundingClientRect().height);
     }
     return ret;
 }
 generateIndexHeadNumbers() {
     const ret = [];
     if (this.rows.length === 0) {
         return ret;
     }
     for (let i = 0; i < this.rows[0].length; i++) {
         ret.push(i);
     }
     return ret;
  }
  generateIndexSideNumbers() {
       const ret = [];
       for ( let i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++ ) {
            ret.push(i);
       }
       return ret;
  }
  cellPadding () {
      let maxRowCellCount = 0;

      for (const row of this.rows) {
          if (row.length > maxRowCellCount) {
             maxRowCellCount = row.length;
          }
      }
      for (const row of this.rows) {
          while (row.length < maxRowCellCount){
              row.push('');
          }
      }
  }
  getHeaderMargin() {
     return new Number(this.indexSide.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width);
  }


}
```

Maybe I should calculate the height of the table-rows dynamically with javascript?

Comment: A little stackblitz could be very helpful :)

Comment: thanks for the note, ive eddited the question

Comment: So, tell me if am not getting it right, you want that table will always show 7 rows, once `add` is clicked , a little vertical scroll appears and so on?

Comment: this is partly correct, I would like to have the parent component determine the size of the table. In app.component.css you can see that the tablecontainer is set to height: 200px , this size should not be exceeded by the whole table-component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `max-height: 200px;` for your class `.table-container` wont add a thing. Instead, and since you choose to separate your components in that way. You should change your `.scroll` class to :

```
.scroll{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 200px; // <-- Added value
}
```

As well as for the `IndexSideComponent` you should change its metadata to :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-index-side',
  template: `<div class="index-side-cell" *ngFor="let n of numbers; let                 i = index;" [style.height.px]="cellHeight[i]">
                    {{n}}
              </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./index-side.component.css'],
  host: {
      class:'max-height' 
  },
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

And then add that class `max-height` to `index-side.component.css`  as following:

```
.max-height {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

---

**PS** : There will be a little inconsistency between side indexes and table cells , that's because of the whole process (***separate indexes from data and choosing pixels in css***), so it will fit better if you make it :

```
.max-height {
      max-height: 183px;
    }
```

*I'd tried this on Chrome browser Version 70.0.3538.102.*

Comment: @H4x9r Welcome !